# y.append(sum(x)) modifies x array by adding sum of x array to x array and i don't know why

Tags: python, arrays, sum, append, python-3.9

So bascially I want to have one array(result) to which I add sum of the second array (array) but
when I try to add to result sum of array it adds to array what should be added to result

```
def some_function(signature, n):

    array = result = signature
    count = 1

    while count <= n:
            print(array)       # prints [1, 1, 1]

            result.append(sum(array))        # Here i don't get it why result.append modifies array.
                                                                     # Without result.append everything works fine
            print(array)       # prints [1, 1, 1, 3]

            array.append(sum(array))    

            print(array)       # prints [1, 1, 1, 3, 6]

        del array[0]

        count += 1

    return result

print(some_function([1, 1, 1], 10))
```

Comment: Because `array` and `results` both point to the same array. `signature` will also change with them.

Answer (score -1):

`array = result = signature` doesn't copy anything. All three variables point to *one and the same list* because assignment doesn't copy.

Because they point the the same list, `result.append(sum(array))` is exactly the same as `array.append(sum(array))`, or `result.append(sum(signature))`, or `signature.append(sum(result))` - it's all the same.

You can copy lists manually:

```
array = signature.copy()
result = signature.copy()
```

Comment: Ye i figured it out couple minutes ago but i haven't known why till now. Thanks for making it clear
I did array = [x for x in signature] and result = [x for x in signature] and it worked